What's the difference between different kinds of Orbits in AE?
There are 3 kinds of Orbits as I see (Orbit Around Cursor Tool, Orbit Around Scene Tool, and Orbit Around Camera POI), but visually they all work the same. I see no difference between these three kinds. What's the difference between them?


They're not the same. Your cursor, your camera's point of interest and your scene can all be a different points in 3D space.
